# v-for in vue update all object in array although the key has been determined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this my code :

```html
      <v-container grid-list-md fluid-fix>
        <div v-for="(data ,c) in chapter.data" :key="c" class="my-3" style="border: 1px solid;">
          <v-layout row wrap px-3>
            <v-flex xs12 sm1>
              <v-text-field v-model="data.num" label="Chapter"></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm3>
              <v-text-field v-model="data.name" label="name"></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm8 d-flex>
              <v-text-field v-model="data.description" label="short info" style="width: 100%;"></v-text-field>
              <div>
                <v-btn class="d-inline-flex servers--btn" color="success" @click="addServer(c)">add server</v-btn>
              </div> 
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>

          <v-container grid-list-md fluid-fix>
            <v-layout wrap v-for="(server ,s) in data.servers" :key="s">
            <v-flex sm12>
              <div class="d-inline-flex">
                <v-autocomplete
                :items="data.serverlist"
                v-model="server.server_id"
                @input="serverChange(data)"
                label="Server"
              ></v-autocomplete>
              </div>
              <div class="d-inline-flex text-xs-right pr-1">
                <v-btn color="orange" class="white--text servers--btn" @click="demo_edit(c,s,server.links)">demo and Edit</v-btn>
              </div>
              <div class="d-inline-flex text-xs-right pr-1" style="float: right;">
                <v-btn color="red" class="white--text servers--btn" @click="delSvOnChap(c,s)">Delete Server</v-btn>
              </div>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex sm12>
              <v-textarea
                v-model="server.links"
                label="box image"
              ></v-textarea>
            </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
```

```js
serverChange(data){
  data.serverlist.forEach(obj => {
    if(_.find(data.servers,{server_id: obj.value})){
      obj.disabled = true
    }else{
      obj.disabled = false
    }
  });

},
```

`serverChange` is in methods 
i want update disabled in the key has been determined , but it's update all object in array

when I log `serverChange` function i just see one object return and that's what I'm looking forward to but when i set disabled for this object , vue update all object in array

I need a solution for this problem .

Comment: I don't see `disabled` being used in the template. Also I'm not sure what are you trying to acomplish here. Are you trying to update single server from `data.serverlist` and to set it to `obj.disabled = true`? Or are you trying to update one server to `obj.disabled = true` and all other servers should be set to `obj.disabled = false`?

Comment: serverlist is a object has disabled in sign

Comment: Your function will result in every item being updated because it will always find a matching pair on each iteration because there's no uniqueness.

Comment: but you see serverChange(data) ? I have determined data and only this data updated